# Running a Kafka container with Docker-outside-of-Docker does not work (topics create, but can't produce messages)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am running a devcontainer (Docker container).

When I try to spin up this service inside of the container:

```yaml
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.6.0
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    ports:
      - 29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      #KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://:29092,CONTROLLER://kafka:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://:29092,CONTROLLER://kafka:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://:29092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: controller,broker
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@kafka:9093
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: true
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
      CLUSTER_ID: MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qk
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader=WARN
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - "cub kafka-ready -b kafka:9092 1 10"
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
```

and run:

`docker ps`, gives me:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                            PORTS                                                     NAMES
1d8ac5ffa96b   confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.6.0   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds (health: starting)   9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32840->29092/tcp, :::32840->29092/tcp   kafka
```

then:

```
kcat -b host.docker.internal:32840 -L
```

returns:

```
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: host.docker.internal:32840/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1 at kafka:29092 (controller)
 0 topics:
```

but if I try to produce into a topic, I get the following error:

```
echo "a" | kcat -b host.docker.internal:32840 -P -t how-is-this-created
%3|1711129154.610|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka:29092/1]: kafka:29092/1: Failed to resolve 'kafka:29092': Name or service not known (after 1ms in state CONNECT)
% ERROR: Local: Host resolution failure: kafka:29092/1: Failed to resolve 'kafka:29092': Name or service not known (after 1ms in state CONNECT)
```

And what's even weirder to me is that the topic does show up in the metadata:

```
kcat -b host.docker.internal:32840 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: host.docker.internal:32840/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1 at kafka:29092 (controller)
 1 topics:
  topic "how-is-this-created" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

This isn't unique to `kcat`; I've tried creating and producing topics using `kafkajs` and the same error appears...

What can I do?

Comment: kcat runs from where? `host.docker.internal` only works within a container. Why do you need to use the host address within a container instead of the kafka container hostname?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am running both `kcat` and the docker-compose within the Docker container. The Docker container mounts the Docker socket from the host: `- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. Mmm. The docker container (dev container) and the Kafka container are not in the same docker-compose, and because of that they don't share the same network. I believe this is what we want, since we will be running tests which spawn multiple Kafkas at the same time